# Show that if $A$ is any subset of a topological space $(X,T)$, then $Int(A) = \complement ( \overline {\complement (A)})$

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing

Show that if $A$ is any subset of a topological space $(X,T)$, then $Int(A) = \complement ( \overline {\complement (A)})$

My reasoning went as follows:

$\overline {\complement (A)} = \complement (A) \cup [\complement (A)]^{'}$

Taking the complement of the above and applying De Morgan's, we arrive at

$A\cap C$ where $C = \{y : y$ is not a limit point of $\complement (A)\}$

Let $x \in A\cap C$, then $x\in A$ and $x$ is not a limit point of $\complement (A)$ so $x \in A$ and $\exists$ a $U$ that is open and $U \cap \complement (A) = \{x\}$ or $\emptyset$ but since $x\in A$ then $U \cap \complement (A) = \emptyset$, so $U \subseteq A$, meaning that $x$ is in an open subset of $A$. But these are precisely the open sets in the union forming $Int(A)$

Meanwhile, we know that $Int(A) = \bigcup_{l \in L} l$ Where each $l \in L$ is open and a subset of $A$, but these are precisely the open sets $U$ described above $\blacksquare$

So, 
1. Is this correct?
2. Can this be written more elegantly without appealing to higher level concepts such as connectedness, balls, etc.
3. Again, because I'm studying topology on my own I would like to know if this question is at the level of an advanced undergraduate level course? Graduate course?

Thanks.

Comment: What is $C(A)$?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I asked the same question, then looked at the code and saw it stands for complement.  Then I changed all of them to $A^{c}$.  Then I googled "notation for set complement" and saw on the wikipedia page that $\complement (A)$ is I guess an accepted notation.  Then I rolled back my edit.

Comment: @user46944 It's a very.. seldomly used notation I think. I've not once seen it. I just prefer $U\setminus A$ where $U$ is the universe set. No confusion to be had there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks correct.

I don't see an easy way to write this without using open sets (that certainly doesn't mean there isn't a way though); after all, this is a proof about basic attributes of a set (the complement, the interior, the boundary, and the closure) in a general topological space, so open sets are all you really have to work with (especially since all of said attributes (save complement) are defined in terms of open sets). Note that you did not have to talk about balls (a metric space idea) nor connectedness.

I would say this is of a middle/advanced undergraduate course, it looks like something that could be in the topology crash course part of a real analysis course (e.g. first chapter Rudin's PMA).